# What payment process do usabilityhub.com use and is it secure?

Tags: security

I was wondering if anyone can tell me what payment provider (e.g. datacash) usability hub use or if they use their own.

This is a shot of their payment flow:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The payment provider they use is [Stripe](https://stripe.com). I found it by inspecting the form they send.

Comment: I think you will find this is the correct answer. Why the down vote?